# Why is the dameon flag useful when using the threading module in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

Given a simple script as the following, why is using daemon flag useful? Maybe this is too simple, but I understand that daemon threads are generally long running background tasks (they are not meant to be waited for as quoted by Raymond Hettinger). So, if I have a task that I am not waiting for and simply start a non-daemon thread and not join, is that psuedo-daemon? It seems the functionality runs the same. Or is this more of a question of memory than processing logic? With the second question Im actually not sure how much resources this script consumes in the aspects of daemon vs non-daemon

```py
from threading import Thread 
import time
import sys
def func():
    for i in range(4):
        print(f"Running Thread-{i}")
        time.sleep(1)


t = Thread(target=func)
# t.daemon = True # nothing seems to change
t.start()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Deleted my answer because it was wrong: I expected `sys.exit()` to exit the program, but when I tried it in the main thread of a python3 program with a non-daemon thread running in the background, it only terminated the main thread. The background thread continued to run. However...

Comment: ...You said, in a comment on my deleted answer, "if using .join() then this should be executed as a non-daemon thread." You _are_ allowed to join a daemon thread. `t.join()` just means, wait for `t` to die. Daemon threads can die, same as ordinary threads. Therefore, you are allowed to wait for a daemon thread to die. There probably isn't any good reason to make a thread be a daemon if you are going to wait for it to die, but you are allowed to do it.

Comment: So there's no issue to wait for daemon threads and you dont have to wait for non-daemons meaning, I can do the inverse of each (keeping in mind there is no good reason a daemon thread should be joined). Just want to know "best-practices" because I wrote a script that executes a thread but can't block main so it starts and doesnt join, and daemon is not True as the thread (function) will die on it's own once completed.

Comment: Whether or not you have to wait for a non-daemon thread depends on what the thread is doing, and why. Suppose thread `nd` is not a daemon. The system will not kill `nd` just because some other thread `t` terminated—not even if `t` is the main thread. So, if all you care about is that `nd` is allowed to finish, for example, writing some file, then there's no need to join it. On the other hand, maybe thread `t` needs to do something with a result that was computed by `nd`. In that case, you might want the `t` thread to call `nd.join()` before `t` tries to use the result.

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to add clarity. I realized that daemon threads show their true colors when a program is exiting. Think of daemons like demons, or despensable, mindless, little pawns. [As mentioned here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#:%7E:text=A%20thread%20can%20be%20flagged,or%20the%20daemon%20constructor%20argument.), Python will abruptly stop daemons, regardless if they have completed or not. So to this point, *Daemon* threads should be used for tasks where completion doesnt matter, and waiting/blocking (ie `.join()` for *Non-Daemons*. **BUT** there *caveats* (or in this case implementations that causes blurred lines) as described below.

**Daemon == Non-daemon** on 2 conditions.

1. Here we are waiting for **ALL THREADS**. Although this "works", the daemon thread should just be a non-daemon. Flagging a thread as daemon, in this case, is giving instructions (to the code reader/maintiner as well) that  these threads all need to be waited for, which doesnt make much sense (and what Raymond said does make sense, "Dont wait for daemons")

```
# Psuedo-code

d_t = DaemonThread

n_t = NonDaemonThread

for thread_ in [d_t, n_t]:
  thread_.start() 

for thread_ in [d_t, n_t]:
  thread_.join()
```

**OR**

2. Here we aren't waiting for *ANY* threads. Not only does this imply that we dont need to wait for tasks BUT now the non-daemon threads, will be abruptly stopped when the program exits, since they are not waited for.

```
# Psuedo-code

d_t = DaemonThread

n_t = NonDaemonThread

for thread_ in [d_t, n_t]:
  thread_.start() 

# never call join()
```

My confusion leading to my original post was 2 parts. I was thinking there might be a difference between a terminated program ( hence trivially including `sys.exit`) vs one that "exits on its own" (context is key but the case of daemon vs non-daemon, no difference) and also that fact that yes, with "misleading" implementation, you *can* wait for daemon threads or abrupty kill non-daemons. Hopefully this helps someone understand Python a little more!

Edit: Improved explanation